# Spring generic bean definition singleton per generic type

Tags: java, spring, generics, autowired

Is it possible to define a generic bean *once* like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public <T> EmitterProcessor<T> emitterProcessor() {
        return EmitterProcessor.create();
    }
}
```

and then have a unique instance per parameterized type `T` so that the following test passes:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public class GenericBeanTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmitterProcessor<String> stringEmitterProcessor;

    @Autowired
    private EmitterProcessor<Integer> integerEmitterProcessor;

    @Test
    public void testExistsAndIsUnique() {
        assertNotNull(stringEmitterProcessor);
        assertNotNull(integerEmitterProcessor);
        assertNotSame(stringEmitterProcessor, integerEmitterProcessor);
    }
}
```

Currently the `stringEmitterProcessor` and `integerEmitterProcessor` are the same object so that the last line in the test `assertNotSame(stringEmitterProcessor, integerEmitterProcessor);` fails.

The only other way that I could imagine requires me to implement a custom `BeanFactory` that would make a distinction based on the parameterized type when autowiring by type.

Comment: What about the prototype scope? In this case Spring will give you a bean of required type on demand.

Comment: I've considered that but if I would want to autowire an instance with the same parameterized type elsewhere then I would receive a new one. So basically the prototype scope should apply on the generic type only but when it comes to the parameterized type T it should behave like a singleton.